# use print in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to use println to print the output in a certain format but not able to get.

```
val vgdataLines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/assignment/t1/vgsales-small.csv")
val vgdata = vgdataLines.map(_.split(";"))

val countPublisher  = vgdata.map(r =>  (r(4),1))
val totalcount= countPublisher.count().toInt
val reducePublisher = countPublisher.reduceByKey(_+_)
def toPercentage(x: Int): Double = {x * 100/totalcount}
val top50 = countPublisher.map(r =>  (r._1, r._2, toPercentage(r._2)))
val top50desc= top50.sortBy(_._2, false)
println(top50desc.take(50))
```

Expected output format:

(Ubisoft,3,15.0)

(Activision,3,15.0)

(Electronic Arts,2,10.0)

(Nintendo,2,10.0)

(Acclaim Entertainment,1,5.0)

(Sega,1,5.0)

(3DO,1,5.0)

(Namco Bandai Games,1,5.0)

Format I am getting:
res1: Array[(String, Int, Double)] = Array((Sony Computer Entertainment,1,5.0), (Activision,1,5.0), (Nintendo,1,5.0), (Activision,1,5.0), (Nintendo,1,5.0), (3DO,1,
5.0), (Sega,1,5.0), (TDK Mediactive,1,5.0), (Capcom,1,5.0), (Atari,1,5.0), (Konami Digital Entertainment,1,5.0), (Namco Bandai Games,1,5.0), (Electronic Arts,1,5.0
), (Kalypso Media,1,5.0), (Ubisoft,1,5.0), (Ubisoft,1,5.0), (Electronic Arts,1,5.0), (Ubisoft,1,5.0), (Acclaim Entertainment,1,5.0), (Activision,1,5.0))

This is when I use top50desc.take(50) instead of println(top50desc.take(50))

Comment: I suppose you'll have to format it yourself with `println(top50desc.take(50).mkString("\n")` or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
val l = List[(String, Int, Double)](
  ("Ubisoft", 3, 15.0),
  ("Activision", 3, 15.0),
  ("Electronic Arts", 2, 10.0)
)
```

note the difference between printing each element of the collection

```
l.foreach(println)
// (Ubisoft,3,15.0)
// (Activision,3,15.0)
// (Electronic Arts,2,10.0)
```

and printing the collection itself

```
println(l)
// List((Ubisoft,3,15.0), (Activision,3,15.0), (Electronic Arts,2,10.0))
```

`foreach` is intendend for when we wish to apply some *side-effect*, such as printing, to each element.